# How to set focus on qPushButton and qLineEdit simultaneously?

Tags: qt, focus

I have a form and in this form a qlineedit should be filled and then a button should be pressed(for example login). I want to have focus on button while typing in qlineedit and clicking on button with pressing enter. how can i do it?

Comment: I set "default" property of login button true and the problem's been solved.

Answer (score 2):

QLineEdit has returnPressed() signal that you can connect to a button for it to do its job.  You don't need simultaneous focus.

Comment: @ Zeks thanks for your reply. I have another button in this form too(cancel). while the qlineedit is empty login button is disabled and cancel button is focused(with blue border). When the first character is entered in qlineedit, login button will be enabled but the focus is on cancel yet. I use returnPressed() signal but again pressing enter couse canceling the form.

Comment: @maryamT you didn't tell us about this other button (cancel)

Comment: @ Nana Osaberiam : yes , I thought it is not related.

Comment: @maryamT show us how you used the `returnPressed()` signal. You must have not implemented it correctly

Comment: @NanaOsaberima: You're right. I correct the implementation and it works. but there is two problem : 1- After finishing related slot, the form will be closed.(it won't happen by clicking on login button which goes to the same slot) 2- The focus (blue border) is on cancel button yet while pressing enter couse login button to act.

Comment: 1. I don't really get what you mean here. Do you mean pressing on return makes the login work but clicking on login button doesn't work? If so, then make another connection so that when this time the login button is clicked instead of return pressed, the same behavior is achieved. Like so;
connect(loginButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(same slot you used for when return is pressed));

2. Set the focus to the login button inside the slot you wrote for the returnPressed() signal. By doing so, the login button accepts focus when return is pressed.

Comment: @ NanaOsaberima : 1- Actully, I exactly did that. The button click signal and return pressed are connected to the same slot but the actions are different. in fact after doing slot method, in the next form, for return pressed the form will be closed automatically. 2- I want to show the user the blue border befor any action.(The focus is on cancel by default)